# RangeFacet based on a timestamp field

Tags: elasticsearch

Can someone enlighten me on how to properly construct a range facet in ElasticSearch`enter code here`?  I have tried several variations of date formats, but always get an exception back.  Here is the simple version:

```
{
  "facets": {
    "hdwm": {
      "range": {
        "field": "@timestamp",
        "ranges": [
          "{'to' : '2013-12-20' }",
          "{'from': '2013-12-20', 'to' : '2013-12-25' }",
          "{'from': '203-12-25' }"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  }
}
```

The @timestamp field is defined as:

```
@timestamp: {
    format: dateOptionalTime
    type: date
}
```

and has values like:

```
@timestamp: 2013-11-20T01:20:37.527Z
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following worked for me. I guess problem is about syntax and usage of '/"

```
{
 "facets": {
    "hdwm": {
      "range": {
        "field": "@timestamp",
        "ranges": [
          {
            "to": "2013-12-30"
          },
          {
            "from": "2013-12-30",
            "to": "2013-12-31"
          },
          {
            "from": "2013-12-31"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  }
}
```

Comment: yes, that work. I just noticed the additional quotes around the curlies.  thanks for the sharp eyes!